# Reschedule a flight on Eva Air after original flight has departed

Tags: missed-flights

As an adjunct to my question here: [Carrying codeine based medicine through Taipei en route to Kuala Lumpur](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/111931/8307)
We've decided to not fly out on our original schedule super early tomorrow morning (TLDR, I'm pretty sick).

I called Eva Air and talked to who I think was a gate agent but I'm not sure. Her only advice was to call reservations in the morning (7 hours after our flight leaves) because I missed the regular hours by about 20 minutes (8:30 AM - 5:30 PM PDT).

We're concerned we may be out the $1500+ in tickets. They don't answer any phones other than the gate agent one outside of those hours so there's no way to notify them we're going to miss the flight and rebook the flight. At a minimum I expect a flight change fee.

Does anyone have experience with Eva Air in a case like this?

Comment: It was a gate agent as we just found out. I'm feeling a lot better so we decided to just go. We very nearly lost our seats because of my phone call. Fortunately we checked in early enough that our seats hasn't been taken yet.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly waht you're after in your question? The answer to 'does anyone have any experience' is probably yes', but what about it are you wanting to know?